# Как работает рендеринг в react?

Tags: reactjs

Допустим, есть компоненты `Root`, в нем `A` `B`. Внутри `B` есть компоненты `B1` и `B2`

В `Root` объявлен стейт. Данные из этого стейта пробрасываются в `B` и затем `B2`.

Если значение в стейте меняется, как сработает рендеринг?

1. Будет перерендерен компонент `Root`, включая все дочерние компоненты.
2. Будут перерендерен компонент `B2`
3. Другое

[image: схема компонентов]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет перерендерен компонент `Root`, включая все дочерние компоненты.

Но есть `memo`, которым можно оборачивать дочерние компоненты. Тогда, если их пропы (через которые передается стейт) не поменялись, то рендер глубже не идет.

Еще есть `useContext`, чтоб перепрыгивать уровни.